# Sublime Text 3 - when I move the mouse left and right, editor window scrolls left and right

Tags: sublimetext3, mouse

When using Sublime Text 3 - when I move the mouse left and right, editor window scrolls left and right instead of simply moving the mouse pointer where I want it to go.

This behavior only started after last reboot, and I did NOT update Sublime recently.

Windows 10 in VDI mode.

I don't observe that behavior in any other software I use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If installed try removing the PlainTasks plugin. In my case this solved the issue. The latest update which came in via Package Control came with the unwanted feature to block the left mouse button in the editor window.

I think generally it's no mistake to check all the installed plugins when this issue occurs.